# Dedicated Server Web/DNS Configuration

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, dedicated

Good evening,

I have a Dedicated Server in a data center and i want configure the serve as DNS SERVER (BIND) and WEB SERVER (WHM/cPanel).

1) Is there a security problems when using a DNS SERVER/WEB SERVER in one physical server ? problems when open ports maybe!

2) Is REALLY important to tell the data center to RDNS of NS1,NS2,DNS1,DNS2 and wait 48h before starting configuring the server ?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have both services on one machine the load/traffic is higher. You have the same secuity issues in both cases (single machine/multible machines).
   You can't run two services on the same port but regularly you run services on their default ports so you shouldn't get into trouble there (HTTP port 80, DNS port 53).
2. It's not important, BUT: If you have email domains on that server, you need to have a `PTR` (aka RDNS) dns record set up to point to that machine (from the `MX` records) otherwise some mail clients/servers may reject or mark your mails as spam/junk.

Comment: First, thank you so much for your answer, i understand now, i have WHM 11.30/cPanel/BIND already installed, that mean the manufacturer has already fix ports/security issues.

Comment: but! i don't understand BIND!, BIND is a dns server software, so is used just for the dns server!, but why BIND is already included with WHM ? and WHM is a web server!

Comment: are BIND is necessary in both cases ? (DNS Server/Web HTTP Server)

Comment: WHM means web host manager as far as I got with google. It's just a package which includes different services and a single administrative environment. That means WHM is not a webserver. Apache HTTPd, lighttpd, nginx, etc are webservers.

Comment: Please unNamed, can you help me to resolve my technical problem ? its just with my own DNS resolver.

Comment: So, i have a dedicated server, work good without any issues, so i want use the server as a "DNS RESOLVERS", that mean is i add "xxx.com = 111.222.333", so when any other server over the web ask for "xxx.com" to my server, then my server answer "111.222.333".

Comment: So i want add domains automatically by API, this is the method that i use so tell me please if is secure: (1) i create an account "mycompany-api.com". (2) i sign in, and uploading php file for adding domains by WHM API. (3) by other account "mycompany.com" i call "mycompany-api.com/api.php" to create a new domain.

Comment: that work good, i get answer by this helpful tools [link](kloth.net/services/nslookup.php), but i don't know if my method is secure.. then know i don't have https!.

Comment: i found many articles talking about adding domains by cPanel Simple DNS Zone Editor, but can just add sub-domain recursing!

Comment: You should open an extra post for your api question. Mark this answer as correct if it answered your actual question(s).